# Does the app run on API level lower than x when AndroidManifest has attribute introduced in x?

Tags: android, android-manifest

My use case is "android:xlargeScreens" in <supports-screen> but I wanted to make the question general.

What will happen if I have that attribute in (introduced in API 9), and try to install the app on a phone running API <9?

A side question is whether I also need to set "android:targetSdkVersion" or "android:minSdkVersion" to 9.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes that are not supported by lower API levels are just ignored. So you will be able to run your application on older devices without any problems (assuming your code not using functions and classes introduced in newer APIs).

The `targetSdkVersion` value is used to detect what your defaults should be, while `minSdkVersion` is used to verify whether your app can even run on the device.

I strongly recommend your reading [Android API Levels](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html)

Comment: Oh, sorry :) You can set either of them to "4" or higher. It probably be better to keep `minSdkVersion` as low as possible, while your `targetSdkVersion` as high as possible.

Comment: No worries. :) But I don't need to set either to 9?

Comment: My app has `minSdkLevel` set to `3` and then `xlargeScreens` set to `true` and it works fine on tablets. If you don't specify the value for `xlargeScreen` then the value of this field depends on what you have in your `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`. So just set `xlargeScreens` to true and forget about sdk versions :)